# Java Program crashed 6 hours in, Core Dump Error

Tags: java, macos, coredump

I have a multi-threaded pipeline program which has a single element of the pipeline that takes multiple hours to calculate for long data.

It works fine for relatively small amounts of data, but for large data it crashed after 6 hours. I got this error:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (safepoint.cpp:310), pid=47713, tid=11267
#  guarantee(PageArmed == 0) failed: invariant
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_65-b17) (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.65-b01 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# DIR/hs_err_pid47713.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Abort trap: 6
DOMAIN$ unlimit -c unlimited
-bash: unlimit: command not found
```

There doesn't seem to be any way to do this on mac. Any ideas why my program crashed?

Comment: DIR/hs_err_pid47713.log .. show that file.

Comment: Note that the command is `ulimit`, not `unlimit`.

Comment: The output says unlimit...     DOMAIN:$ unlimited -c unlimited
-bash: unlimited: command not found

Comment: Its a long file. Any particular parts of interest?

Answer (score 1):

If you search Google, these types of `guarantee(PageArmed == 0) failed: invariant` JVM crashes have been around in Oracle JDK versions 6, 7, and 8.

A couple of "easy" things you can try to workaround this:

1) Change the version of the JRE you're running, e.g. try upgrading to a newer version than `1.8.0_65`;

2) Upgrade your OS, e.g. are you running an older version of Linux?

3) You mention for large amounts of data this is occurring.  Have you considered using a profiler such as YourKit, to study the thread and heap memory usage in the JVM in order to rule them out as being a problem?

Comment: I'm on a mac, and I don't have that kind of access to it. I know precisely which thread is the problem, since it is a bottleneck for the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

This is an JVM compiler issue,
Internal Error (safepoint.cpp:310), pid=47713, tid=11267

## guarantee(PageArmed == 0) failed: invariant

suggest that one of the thread has unable to reach to safepoint.
When a safepoint is pending the VMThread will wait until all thread's that are _thread_in_Java transition to another state, at which they are either already safepoint-safe [_thread_blocked, _thread_in_native] or they will enter into a handshake with the VMThread to become safe (_thread_in_VM)
The most likely cause is an uncounted compiler loop which has no safepoint polls generated in it
You should report to http://bugreport.java.com/ along with test case to reproduce this issue.